# looking for an anime about a fighting school with special powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember seeing an anime about a guy who finds a female friend when entering a (military?) academy where they are trained to fight monsters or something. the academy had a stupid rule they dont agree on and if they want to change it they have to fight the committee so this guy ends up fighting against the best girl with the best special item. the special items give them specific weapons. (I think his was an armor like iron man) he loses but they end up going on a mission together. any idea on the name?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you watch this? Also, can you describe what any of the characters looked like, especially hair colour?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].